# Laravel 5.4 and Vue 2.0.1 Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.4

I am using Vue Templating with the new Laravel 5.4. In my **Office.vue** I have this code.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component! {{ message}} | {{ type}} | {{ number }}
                    </div>
                    <span id="vue"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            return this.displayOffices();
        },
        data: function(){
            return { 
                message: "aw",
                type: "test",
                number: 2 
            }
        },
        methods: {
            displayOffices: function(){
                this.$http.get('/vueOffice', function(course) {
                    console.log(course);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Displaying the data is good and well work but I got error with

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

which is in **this.$http.get**

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the data from that route which returns JSON data.

I need help fixing this error, been trying to search for an answer but everyone with different ways in implementing Vuejs.

Comment: If your are  using `axios` instead of `vue-resource`  then replace `this.$http` with `axios`.

Comment: hi I can mark this as accepted, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using `axios` instead of `vue-resource` then replace `this.$http` with `axios`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to install the [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) before you can use `this.$http.get`

or you can install [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) and use `axios.get` instead of `this.$http.get`

Comment: I have install vue-resource, and re-build, but still problem exist, I'm using axios now, and it's working great

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use this.$http.get as Vue wants to move away from supporting it. They recommend to use libraries using axios. You can then use `this.axios.get()`.

```
self.axios
  .get(apiUrl, {
    params: this.formData,
  })
  .then((response) => {

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to add the following code to your file:

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

Comment: No, don't do it. Why would you? It's so bad practice

Answer (score 0):

**Add this** `require('vue-resource');` in your file 
 
`/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` 
 
After:  
 
`window.Vue = require('vue');`